# Moq error - expected a method with 'bool IsAny(HttpResponseMessage)'

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I want to mock this method:

```
public HttpClient CreateHttpClientForJwt(Func<HttpResponseMessage, bool> isUnauthenticated, int timeoutSeconds)
{
    var client = Mvx.Resolve<IPlatformOperationProvider>().CreateHttpClient(timeoutSeconds);
    return new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpMessageHandler(this, client, AuthenticationUtils.AddJwtToRequest, isUnauthenticated,_loggingService));
}
```

my attempt:

```
authenticatedRequestServiceMock.Setup(sm => sm.CreateHttpClientForJwt(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<HttpResponseMessage, bool>>>, 5)).Returns(stubHttpClient.Object);
```

I'm getting this error in on the `IsAny` Visual studio before compilation:

> expected a method with `'bool IsAny(HttpResponseMessage)'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Expression in

```
authenticatedRequestServiceMock
    .Setup(sm => sm.CreateHttpClientForJwt(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<HttpResponseMessage, bool>>>, 5))
    .Returns(stubHttpClient.Object);
```

and update the `It.IsAny` to

```
authenticatedRequestServiceMock
    .Setup(sm => sm.CreateHttpClientForJwt(It.IsAny<Func<HttpResponseMessage, bool>>(), 5))
    .Returns(stubHttpClient.Object);
```

`It.IsAny<TValue>()` is a method but you were calling it like a property. You also described the method as expecting a `Func` but setup with an `Expression<Func<>>`